# Materialized View creation using ANSI coding standards

Tags: oracle11g, materialized-views

I am working on Oracle 11g2 and came across the below scenario can anyone explain me the reason behind it. I could not find a proper documentation for the same.

**Issue:**
I am not able to create **FAST REFRESH Materialized View** using the below query which contains ANSI coding standards but if I use conventional coding standards then I can create it.
Let me know if any further information is required.

```
    **EMP Table:**
    EMP_ID   NUMBER
    EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(100)
    DEPT_ID  NUMBER

    **DEPT Table:**
    DEPT_ID   NUMBER
    DEPT_NAME VARCHAR2(100)


    --Mat View Logs creation
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON EMP WITH ROWID ;
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON DEPT WITH ROWID;

     CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW EMP_DEPT_MV
     REFRESH  FAST
     AS
     SELECT EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,EMP.DEPT_ID,DEPT_NAME,EMP.ROWID E_R,DEPT.ROWID D_R
     FROM   EMP
     INNER
     JOIN   DEPT
     ON     EMP.DEPT_ID=DEPT.DEPT_ID;

**SQL Error: ORA-12015: cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query
12015. 00000 -  "cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query"**


 CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW EMP_DEPT_MV
 REFRESH  FAST
 AS
 SELECT EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,EMP.DEPT_ID,DEPT_NAME,EMP.ROWID E_R,DEPT.ROWID D_R
 FROM   EMP,DEPT
 WHERE  EMP.DEPT_ID=DEPT.DEPT_ID;

 **Materialized view EMP_DEPT_MV created.**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not use **ANSI** join syntax, use the old Oracle join syntax. It is a bug in Oracle.

Also fom oracle docs http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/basicmv.htm,

Defining queries for materialized views with **joins only and no aggregates** have the following restrictions on fast refresh:

- All restrictions from "General Restrictions on Fast Refresh".[General restriction](http://maslopo.blogspot.ch/2011/09/restrictions-on-fast-refresh-on.html?m=1)
- They cannot have GROUP BY clauses or aggregates.
- Rowids of all the tables in the FROM list must appear in the SELECT
  list of the query.
- Materialized view logs must exist with rowids for all the base tables
  in the FROM list of the query.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and the link. Any idea about the Oracle bug ID / Number related to this.

Comment: Check Doc ID 1087507.1 https://blogs.oracle.com/db/entry/master_note_for_mview_ora-_error_diagnosis_for_materialized_view_create_or_refresh